# Loss of voltage when connecting an outdoor light fixture

Tags: voltage

I am stuck.  I have an outdoor light post.  A wire to the post was cut and was replaced.  At the post, I have 120
volts off of the wire.  When I connect the light fixture I am only getting 48 volts.  I tried two new light fixtures and get the same result.  And, when I disconnect the wires, a voltage check goes back to 120 volts on the main wire. Any ideas?

Comment: We'd need to know more about where and how you are measuring those voltages. From what wire to what other wire?

Comment: Black to black and red to white…and red to ground.  Using Klein voltage meter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Also called Ghost Voltage.

You would measure 120 Volt, but as soon you draw some current the Voltage drops or goes to zero.

Usually the cause is bad wire connection (loose).

Comment: Would the loose wire be before the post?  There are junctions, but I have triple checked those.  Or do you mean a loose wire at the fixture?

Comment: Volt meter will not tell you, but if you measure at junctions, then turn the load, it will tell you, where the drop is

Comment: You're getting two concepts confused. Phantom (or ghost) voltage is induced voltage that is never there at a significant current level. It is usually *not* the full 120V. On the other hand, a loose connection (which you indicate as the cause, and which I agree is the likely problem here) will show 120V but show much less under load because of high resistance.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  I will test for low voltage at each junction.

Comment: @Clif, great that would show you where the 120 V drops.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, is there a name for when 120 Volt show on the meter, but disappear at load ?

Comment: @Cliff Not just test for low voltage. In fact, you probably won't see that. Look for any loose screw connections, backstabs (whether they appear loose or not), loose wire nuts, etc.

Comment: I ordered a meter that tests for voltage and low voltage.  (Puts a load on it).  Klein MM700

Comment: Ok, so I tested the lines at each junction.  Found the culprit.  Bad wire underground.  Will have to run a new 35 foot line.  The adventure continues.  Btw, the MM700 worked as advertised.  Showed the low voltage or ghost voltage.

Comment: @Cliff glad I could help, and still some idiot gave me negative vote?